# GUIMiner won't start mining on Slush's pool

Tags: mining-pools, mining-software, connection

I started co-mining on [Slush's pool](https://mining.bitcoin.cz/stats/) successfully for about 48 hours, but from there on I haven't been able to connect to it again. It logs in the console this, no matter if I'm using a valid worker and password or not:

```
2013-05-26 12:55:19: Listener for "Default" started
2013-05-26 12:55:20: Listener for "Default": api2.bitcoin.cz:8332 26/05/2013 12:55:20, checking for stratum...
2013-05-26 12:55:20: Listener for "Default": api2.bitcoin.cz:8332 26/05/2013 12:55:20, started OpenCL miner on platform 0, device 0 (Turks)
2013-05-26 12:55:20: Listener for "Default": api2.bitcoin.cz:8332 26/05/2013 12:55:20, no response to getwork, using as stratum
2013-05-26 12:55:20: Listener for "Default": api2.bitcoin.cz:8332 26/05/2013 12:55:20,  No JSON object could be decoded
2013-05-26 12:55:30: Listener for "Default": api2.bitcoin.cz:8332 26/05/2013 12:55:30, Failed to subscribe
2013-05-26 12:55:32: Listener for "Default": api2.bitcoin.cz:8332 26/05/2013 12:55:32, IO errors - 1, tolerance 2
2013-05-26 12:55:33: Listener for "Default" shutting down
```

Of course, I've checked my connection, and I've started [GUIMiner](http://guiminer.org/) with administrator privileges. I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that in GUIMiner, the URL for **Slush's pool** is:

> api2.bitcoin.cz:8332

That address has been deprecated, and it falls back to the *GetWork* protocol. From [Slush's Pool news](http://mining.bitcoin.cz/):

> 10.03.2013
>   Default mining URL for *Stratum* is `stratum.bitcoin.cz:3333`. If you're still using `api.bitcoin.cz`, please fix your URL to prevent fallback to deprecated *Getwork* protocol.

In the GUIMiner interface, instead of choosing "Slush's Pool" from the dropdown menu, choose "other" and then enter

**http://api.bitcoin.cz:8332**

or

**stratum.bitcoin.cz:3333**

Comment: Nice, it worked!

Comment: Thank you this was verry helpfull, stratum.bitcoin.cz:3333 worked for me.

Comment: i had the exact same problem but following ur instructions didnt help me a bit. whats wrong?

Comment: When I tried it with the CPU miner (*not GPU*), *api.bitcoin.cz:8332* worked, but *stratum.bitcoin.cz:3333* did **not** work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `stratum.bitcoin.cz` and port `3333` in GUIMiner, **not** like http://stratum.bitcoin.cz:3333 that was mensioned in another answer.